# Is it possible to validate top-level array by class-validator in NestJS?

Tags: validation, nestjs, dto, class-validator

So I have NestJS with global validation pipe: `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe())`

Is it possible to validate TOP LEVEL ARRAY like?

```
[{
  "id":1,
  "name":"John"
}, {
  "id":2,
  "name":"Jane"
}]
```

I've read the docs, but they suggest only nested array validation, so payload needs to be like

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Jane"
    }
  ]
}
```

But question is about validation top-level array, not nesting it into additional variable.

For now my best idea is extend `ValidationPipe` to translate payload from 1st example to payload in 2nd example.
But I'm looking something like `yup.array()` which works fine at top level and wondering if `class-validator` missing top-level array validation, or if I'm missing something from docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the docs mention](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) there's the [`ParseArrayPipe`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/pipes/parse-array.pipe.ts) which ends up running the `ValidationPipe` against an array of the provided DTO type. You **must** bind this pipe manually due to how Typescript handles the reflection of generics (which arrays are considered to be). This is why it's usually *preferred* to make the array a property of an object rather than a top-level value